# ASYNC and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous

I've just been reading up on the upcoming changes to c# and VB.Net using the new ASYNC and AWAIT keywords for asynchronous coding. Has anyone heard anything about whether or not this is going to be usable for async db calls via EF?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are evaluating the possibility of adding async capabilities to EF in the future, using the new Task-based pattern. It is too early to say whether and when this will happen but any information about the scenarios in which you expect to be able to take advantage of this feature will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: Async support has been added in EF6.**

Comment: Thanks divega-its good to hear this from the source. Our async needs are pretty basic, we simply want better UI responsiveness.  We are developing a large (for us) case management system for the Dept of Justice in my province (in Canada).  The system is built with WPF/MVVM/EF/SQL Server.  A number of our UI's contain summaries of information pulled from numerous tables in the db (as well as other systems) and we'd like the ability to load those 'sections' of data while the user continues to work.Right now we just throw up the standard 'please wait' while the data is being retrieved.Thanks.

Comment: Just a follow up question: using the current CTP version of Task-based async can we create async functions that leverage LINQ-to-Entities in order to interact with the db?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer: to your follow up question: No. The CTP only includes Task-based async extension methods for compoenents that currently support async using previous async patterns. Since EF doesn't currently support async operation with any pattern, Task-based async support cannot be added without changes to the product.

Comment: Regarding the original comment, thanks a lot for giving us context on how you plan to use Task-based async support. One thing that comes to mind is that you can achieve a similar benefits by executing your data access layer in a background thread. Have you considered doing this?

Comment: Sorry for my delay this time. We've mulled it over a bit but given our time constraints we've decided its better just to continue on as we are currently doing. The UI delays are relatively minor - we just wanted to add a bit of polish. BTW: we are very impressed with the efficient SQL being produced by the latest EF version. Very rarely are we getting any 'Recently Expensive Query' occurances with our EF-based apps - and we're running some pretty hefty LINQ against EF in a few places.

Comment: @divega Do you have any update on this scenario? I want to be able to run async so I can lower the number of threads used on the webserver. asp.net mvc + async controllers would be used and EF should be able to  support this.

Comment: @divega please provide some way to do task base asynchronous programming with EF along with async CTP. It is the core missing point now. I am not sure if this the best practice but a great guy wrote an extension: http://philsversion.com/2011/09/07/async-entity-framework-queries/ is this the right way of doing that?

Comment: @tugberk: just for other people that haven't seen the other thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481619/ef-objectqueryt-context-parameters-connection-properties-equivalent-on-dbset/9507107#comment12048422_9507107), a workaround like this can be useful if you understand it has some limitations. I am taking note of all the great feedback. We agree async support in EF is an important addition.