# EF ObjectQuery<T> Context, Parameters, Connection properties equivalent on DbSet<T>

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

In the earlier versions of Entity Framework, we were able to reach the `Context` out of `ObjectQuery` in order to read `Parameters`, `Connection`, etc. as below:

```
var query = (ObjectQuery<T>)source;

cmd.Connection = (SqlConnection)((EntityConnection)query.Context.Connection).StoreConnection;
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(
    query.Parameters.Select(x => new SqlParameter(
        x.Name, x.Value ?? DBNull.Value)
    ).ToArray()
);
```

When I look at the `DbSet<T>` object, I am unable to find any equivalent of this. My purpose here is to create extensions which will manipulate the query and get the result out of it.

Here is an instance: http://philsversion.com/2011/09/07/async-entity-framework-queries

Or should I write the extension for `DbContext` class and work with `Set` method?

Any idea?

**Edit**

Here is what I did so far. Basic implementation so far but certainly not ready for production. Any suggestions on this?

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(this DbContext @this, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    where T : class {

        var query = (predicate != null) ? @this.Set<T>().Where(predicate) : @this.Set<T>();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.Connection = (SqlConnection)(@this.Database.Connection);
        cmd.CommandText = query.ToString();

        if (cmd.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) { 

            cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cmd.Connection.ConnectionString) {
                AsynchronousProcessing = true
            }.ToString();

            cmd.Connection.Open();
        }

        cmd.Disposed += (o, e) => {

            cmd.Clone();
        };

        var source = ((IObjectContextAdapter)@this).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(
            await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()
        );

        return source;
}
```

Comment: I would love a extensionmethod like AsSync on the IQueryable interface with POCO. Sorry not to have an answer, but i did vote at http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015385-support-for-asynchronous-queries

Comment: @rfcdejong I voted up as well. Also, I've written something. Please have a look at updated question.

Comment: It looks really hopefull ;) But keep in mind there might be different ConnectionStates beside Closed in the future. Like Connecting, Executing, Fetching and Broken.

Comment: @rfcdejong it is not healthy yet and my knowledge can get that this far. I am begging the ef team for the extension for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice workaround, although I don't think you can make it much more generally applicable than what you already have.

A few things to keep in mind:
- Depending on the EF query, e.g. if you are using Include or not, the columns returned in the reader might not match the properties in the type T you are passsing.
- Depending on whether you have inheritance in your model, the T that you pass to translate may not always be the right thing to materialize for every row returned.
- After the task returned by ExecuteReaderAsync completes, you still have to retrieve each row, which depending on the execution plan for the query and the latency you are getting with the server is potentially also a blocking operation.

Async support is not coming to EF in 5.0 but we worked with other teams to make sure we have all the necessary building blocks included in .NET 4.5 and the feature is pretty high in our priority list. I encourage you to [vote for it in our UserVoice site](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015385-support-for-asynchronous-queries).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I already voted up. As you do, I don't think this workaround would be something further than personal use. I am also not sure I'd use this in prod. I really think that you should make this available as soon as possible. All the async support with C# 5.0, this is a must. Maybe in a separate extensions nuget package as CTP, just like you did with migrations feature. Would that work out?

Comment: I agree async is important (and the language support is great!). We cannot release async for EF in a separate package though, it involves changes pretty deep in the core.

Comment: I see now. Well, at least you are aware of this need and thanks for the information. I hope it will be there soon.